# SASS (.sass) Why is does this variable mess everything up?

Tags: css, sass, atom-editor

I am new to sass and I cannot, for the life of me, figure out why this particular instance of a variable is messing up my .css output. I am using Atom.io as my text editor and the plugin sass-autocompile as my sass compiler.

**Here's my code**

Sass:

```html
$white: #fdfcfc
$black: #040A14

.dark-btn
  color: $white
  display: block
  font-weight: bold
  margin: auto
  background: $black
  padding: 10px
  width: 200px
  text-align: center
  &:hover
    background: $gray
    animation-name: popUp
    animation-fill-mode: forwards
    animation-duration: 200ms
```

After it compiles I get this:

```html
.dark-btn {
  color: #fdfcfc;
  color-display: block;
  color-font-weight: bold;
  color-margin: auto;
  color-background: #040A14;
  color-padding: 10px;
  color-width: 200px;
  color-text-align: center;
}

.dark-btn:hover {
  background: #333;
  animation-name: popUp;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-duration: 200ms;
}
```

Its basically adding "color-" to everything. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Less code dump and more isolate example of 'the variable', including showing the expected case and/or the case without 'the variable'.

Comment: What happens if enabling visible whitespace in Atom?

Comment: Thanks, there were spaces where there should have been tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: There were spaces where there should have been tabs. Once I removed the spaces and replaced with them with tabs, everything compiled correctly.